# How to use Rails' simple_format with special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, arbre

On Rails 3.2.13, `simple_format` does not return what I expect it to do, on an admittedly convoluted case:

```
> simple_format("a <= 2, b < 4")
"<p>a &lt; 4</p>"
```

Since this case does not seem to work properly (I'm losing half my string!), is there a way to pre-escape special characters so that it works everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) the string yourself:

```
ERB::Util.h("a <= 2, b < 4")
#=> "a &lt;= 2, b &lt; 4"

simple_format(ERB::Util.h("a <= 2, b < 4"))
#=> "<p>a &lt;= 2, b &lt; 4</p>"
```

From within views, you can omit `ERB::Util.` and just call `h`

Comment: Ah, thanks, I found références to `h` everywhere, but ActiveAdmin pages don't work with views!